# San Marino retirement requirements

Tags: san-marino

Looking for info on retirement rules in different countries.  Frustrating because many web search hits are made by people who seem to believe retirement doesn't exist.  Governments being what they are, it's often hard to find what must be in there somewhere.

But San Marino is even worse, because it seems impossible to filter out all the pages about retirement homes in San Marino, California.  I finally found two pages.  One says nothing about requirements, merely warning that it's expensive (which doesn't seem to be accurate).  The other says the visa types are tourist, working, student and delegation—no retirement.  It also implies you need one of those visas to get in, but in fact, there were no border checks when we went in in 2013.

I have limited Italian reading skills, but they aren't adequate to do a web search.  Can someone point me to a page that tells what a U.S. citizen must do to legally retire there?

Update: The [*Residenza atipica soggetta a regime fiscale agevolato*](https://www.esteri.sm/pub2/EsteriSM/Servizi-per-utenza/Permessi-di-Soggiorno-e-Residenze.html) appears to be an option, but it does not list the requirements—has a very long list of citations to the laws governing the *anagrafica*, *elettiva*, and *soggiorno* but not the *atipica*.

Comment: Not quite what you’re looking for, but there’s an email address for enquiries about residence permits at the San Marino MoFA site http://www.esteri.sm/on-line/en/home/link/stay-and-residence-permits.html I don’t know if this list of retirement visas by country is complete, but San Marino doesn’t seem to feature https://www.escapeartist.com/residency-options-country/

Comment: That's probably the closest to an answer I'm going to get.  The second one only has forty countries (out of around two hundred).  Of course, living in Italy close to San Marino is practically the same, but I'm trying to make a "more complete list."

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the citations in [*Residenza atipica soggetta a regime fiscale agevolato*](https://www.esteri.sm/pub2/EsteriSM/Servizi-per-utenza/Permessi-di-Soggiorno-e-Residenze.html).  I saw the word *soggiorno* but didn’t notice that those links are for both *soggiorno* **and** *residenza*.  The [first citation](https://www.esteri.sm/pub2/EsteriSM/dam/jcr:b80dd568-d8c7-42af-8184-b82bd851e68b/32%20Residenza%20-%20soggiorno%20ordinario%20art.%2016%20comma%203%20lettera%20A-Professionista%20Sanitario,%20Finanziario,%20Assicurativo.pdf) identifies the information required without specifics, e.g., proof of sufficient income but without defining how much is sufficient.